# Selection paint brush does not highlight the selected hair

Tags: mesh, particles, sculpting, hair, selection-tools

Can't solve this problem no matter I do.

The brush works fine but does not highlight the selected hair strands.

I already tried to change selection oppacity, but still no effect.
[image]